# Pivotal HAWQ pg_restore :unexpected end of file

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, hawq

When  trying to restore backup in Hawq database first time. Getting this error.

**Input command**

I tried running this command

```
[gpadmin@mdsby backup]$ pg_restore -d gpadminrestore gpadmin_10-01-2017
```

**Error :**

**pg_restore: [custom archiver] unexpected end of file**

Answer (score 0):

probably wrong format.
try to cat the backup file. if it is all sql statement, you need to use psql -f to load the data. 
BTW, if the data size is big, don't use pg_backup and pg_restore. Those backup and restore go through master and will be slow.